# Rename file in Jira script editor problem error: File doesn't exist on the server filesystem

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-agile

[image]

I am using the Jira script editor and I just want to change the name of my file from CreateMultipleSubtasks/scriptFragment_Condition_CreateMultipleSubtasks.groovy to a new name: CreateMultipleSubtasks/scriptFragment_condition_CreateMultipleSubtasks.groovy

The only change is to make the C of the condition word smaller and I receive the error message shown above. I have no idea why. I have right clicked on my file in ths script editor and I have chosen the option rename and I get this error. Anyone knows how to change the upper case C to a lower case c in the script editor of Jira?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new character needs to be appended to the file name. Changing a lowercase letter to an uppercase one is not recognized as a name change so a new character needs to be added and then the lower case change can be applied and it would work.